# Video streaming in node js

Tags: node.js, video-streaming

I am struggling to stream Bosch camera in my application.We have bosch camera setup within the vpn.We have to embed that camera streaming in our application.We have vpn credentials and camera credentials.Does anyone help me to figure out the solution ?
Camera Model (FLEXIDOME IP starlight 8000i).We are using node js as backend server and react js in the frontend.

Comment: The product you mention contains an embedded web server to deliver pages. [One of those pages contains a live stream](https://resources-boschsecurity-cdn.azureedge.net/public/documents/FLEXIDOME_IP_starlig_Operation_Manual_enUS_69886472331.pdf). Here's where your browser's View Source feature is your friend. Look at how that live streaming page works, and copy the relevant elements. Or put the whole streaming page into an `<iframe>` in your web app. Or ask the vendor for help. They do claim that Internet Explorer is the best browser for their app, so they may not be much help. Still, ask.

Comment: We tried using iframe but the problem is camera is within the VPN.

Comment: Ok, then, your problem is far more complex than your question explains. You probably should work out the networking details of the problem, and then ask another question. How do you intend to move the video data stream from inside your vpn to where it needs to be viewed?

Comment: Is it possible to connect to VPN first in Node js first and then stream the camera ?

Comment: If a browser can't see through the vpn then neither can a nodejs server. You might be able to deploy a nodejs server that listens for connections outside your vpn, and uses another interface to connect, inside the vpn, to the cam. But it's pointless to start building the software until you understand the network engineering situation. And, make sure your network security people will let you do this. Because cybercreeps.